# PaperTrail and batch versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

In my Rails app, I have a series of objects that can be reordered on the page (each object saves its position relative to other objects on the page).  I'd like to do some versioning on how these objects are arranged so that I can implement undo/redo buttons.

I thought that the [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem might be a good option for saving a tree structure of how these objects are sorted, but the issue is that when the user rearranges the objects, the position of some objects might change while others do not, and PaperTrail only seems to save versions when the object has been changed.  What I'd really like is something that can save a snapshot of the state of all objects in the model. Is there any way to force PaperTrail to save a version so that I could just call something like

```
@objects.each do |object|
    @object = object.versions.scoped.last
    @version = Version.find(@object)
    @version.reify.save!
end
```

for undoing changes?  Or is there some better way to accomplish this?

For example (I'm sorting 2D arrays):

Before making changes:

```
name   | position | ancestry
Step 0 |    0     |   0
Step 1 |    1     |  371
Step 2 |    2     |  371
```

After making changes:

```
name   | position | ancestry
Step 0 |    0     |   0
Step 1 |    1     |  371
Step 2 |    2     |  371/374
```

After trying to do an undo:

```
name   | position | ancestry
Step 0 |    0     |   0
Step 1 |    2     |  371
Step 2 |    2     |  371
```

Notice how for Step 1, the position should be 1, but since the object didn't change from before and after the rearranging, it reverted to the last saved version that was unique, which is incorrect.

Comment: My first guess, would be to save all the objects when one moves. And maybe use that "all objects position" as an attribute to a model that is associated with your objects. That make sense?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm doing now; when one object moves, I save all objects and their position.  the issue is that for some objects, the position changes, and for others, it doesn't, so it doesn't seem as straightforward as calling "last" on all the objects

Comment: I believe it does. You're saving a state that all the objects share as a single attribute ( even though sometimes objects would be the same in several states. )

Comment: Unfortunately, I've confirmed that it isn't working that way (I've edited my question to include an example).